# Most Rich Pantone Black

Tags: print-design

What is the richest black that Pantone have for Logo printing? I want something to appear really black and not tinted (Something similar to the registration black in CMYK which is a 100% of the 4 colors).

I heard though that printing on 100% from all colors will damage the paper (it will be over-soaked or so I guess). Moreover, I am not sure if I can use Pantone+CMYK in this case?

Comment: I wonder if one could print Vantablack, i would like to see face of the person who accepts the bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically one does a Pantone Black so it's a **solid ink.** As a solid ink, at 100%, *any* Pantone black will not have the "greying" tendency CMYK black may have. So really *any* Pantone Black will be more solid than a CMYK black.

For CMYK reproduction, a **Rich Black** can be favorable- i.e. 40C40Y040M90K, or similar (talk to the printer for Rich Black breakouts - this is *only an example*. Every print provider may have their own rich black formula.)

You can do CMYK+Spot.. It will cost much more as a 5 color run though. So you'd be increasing production costs for *everything* with the logo on it. And even with 5 color you may still bound by ink limits at times.

You can *never* do 100C100M100Y100K.. Not *ever*. Stock simply will **not** hold that much ink. It smears and runs and can't be printed. Ink limits are there for technical reasons and not arbitrarily set.

CMYK (rich black) or a straight Pantone are good enough for every major billion dollar corporation. I doubt you really need a 5 color run for a logo.

---

Be aware that because a screen or application may make 100C100M100Y100K appear deeper, that is just on screen with *light*. It's not the same as on paper with ink. Anything less that that will *always* look "less black" on screen due to the nature of color profiles. And depending upon your exact color settings the variation can be small or great.

Answer (score 1):

If the result is to make the black really 'pop' you could assign a varnish plate - this could be a matt or gloss (or other effect) - the degree of 'pop' could be enhanced by the the paper stock choice. Talk to your print provider on options.